# Does Stripe connect account transfer payment to connected account in test mode?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am testing with Stripe Connect Account now. I was able to take payments from customers on behalf of the connected account. I am using Standard Account. In "Payment Details", Statement descriptor shows connected account business name. However, after many days the connected account never received any payment. Doc states payout will be automatically transferred in 2 days for standard account but it never happened. I am wondering whether payout is supported in test mode or I missed anything?

Comment: You should reach out to Stripe support directly, you're unlikely to get much help on SO as this is likely specific to your Stripe account. https://support.stripe.com/contact

Answer (score 0):

Reached out Stripe support. According to the person I spoke to, test mode does not pay out to connected account. To test payout for connected account, it needs to be in "Live Mode".  The minimum charge for Live Mode is 50 cents.